# AssertionFailedError deleteById

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm new to Junit/Mockito and this is my very first test for employee service class.

I'm wondering if this test of `deleteById` method does work well.

`assertThat(expectedEmployee).isNull();` fails with message:

```
AssertionFailError: 
Expected: null. Actual: Employee(id=1).
```

However `verify(employeeRepository).deleteById(employee.getId());` works well.

When I'm testing the code with postman, the method works and an employee is deleted.

Employee repository:

```
    @Repository
    public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    }
```

Employee service:

```
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
            employeeRepository.deleteById(id);
        }
```

Employee controller:

```
    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
        public void deleteEmployeeById(@PathVariable Long id) {
            employeeManager.deleteById(id);
        }
```

Test class:

```
      @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
        class EmployeeManagerTest {
    
        @Mock
        private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
        @InjectMocks
        private EmployeeManager employeeManager;
    

        @Test
        void shouldDeleteEmployeeById() {
            
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setId(1L);

            when(employeeRepository.findById(employee.getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(employee));
        
            employeeManager.deleteById(employee.getId());
            
            Employee expectedEmployee = employeeManager.findById(employee.getId()).get();
            
            verify(employeeRepository).deleteById(employee.getId()); -> this works well 
            
           // assertThat(expectedEmployee).isNull(); // -> this fails
        }
```

Comment: Your assertion means nothing. Because you mock it to return something, and then you assert the same thing :) It fails because you mocked it to return `Option.of(employee)`, but basically, that assertion should not exist, because it means nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertion fails, because you mocked the method

```
when(employeeRepository.findById(employee.getId())).thenReturn('something that is not null');
```

This means, that if you call that method in the test, it will return you the optional with the employee.

Comment: Thank you for your help:)